# Can I define the number of nodes in Coreldraw?

Tags: corel-draw, cutter

I use Corel to produce hpgl files that feed a CNC wire cutter.
If I want the CNC to cut a different shape at each end it will do it but only if the files for each end have the same number of nodes.  How do I define the number of nodes on one curve and the exact same number of nodes on another curve in order that my CNC will be happy.

Comment: Are the shapes even possible with the same number of nodes? Bezier curve nodes have purpose. If they alter a shape, you can't simply remove them in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the shape tool to select all the nodes in your shape, then drag the Reduce nodes value (in the property bar at the top) upwards/to the right (by how much is up to you), you'll be able to limit the number of nodes (you should be able to see how many nodes you have selected in the status bar).

Between that and the add/remove node option in the property bar, you should be able to make things work to your liking.

However, as Scott said, note that reducing nodes may result in your curves changing.